# Error googleapi: Error 403: Forbidden, forbidden while uploading apk to Google play with Bitrise

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, bitrise

I using Bitrise to upload my apk to google play. I am getting **googleapi: Error 403: Forbidden, forbidden** on the start of this workflow. I gave all permissions to the service account that I'm using. Can someone please help me with this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You may want to think about giving some extra details within your question. Show some code so others can gather what might be causing the issue. There is a handy link here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example